# How to display "No Data Found" or any custom message in Bar Chart when there is no data in source in looker studio

Tags: looker-studio

I want to display any custom error message ex "No data Found in this Chart" when there is no data for the chart(measure and dimension) in looker studio

Need to display error message while no data in source for looker studio

Answer (score -1):

I think it might be a bit complex to find a solution from Match Attribute.
You may have to create custom dimensions to arrive at the solution. First, you can create a dimension to extract the most recent Monday using max(date_truc(timestamp, week(Monday)))   (let's call it latest_MON). Then you can create another dimension that would calculate the difference between latest_MON and timestamp. 
With this, for each record, you will have a dimension giving you the parameter to calculate the 30 days from the recent Monday, and then that can be used to filter out the records. Hey, I think it might be a bit complex to find a solution from Match Attribute.
You may have to create custom dimensions to arrive at the solution. First, you can create a dimension to extract the most recent Monday using max(date_truc(timestamp, week(Monday))) (let's call it latest_MON). Then you can create another dimension that would calculate the difference between latest_MON and timestamp. 
With this, for each record, you will have a dimension giving you the parameter to calculate the 30 days from the recent Monday, and then that can be used to filter out the records.